# Running a subroutine provided by a docker image within the main script

Tags: python, docker, pip

What is the best practice when wanting to run a library that is given by a docker image in a python program?

I'm trying to use the library: https://github.com/oseledets/ttpy , in one of my python scripts but it seems like installing it from pip is not working due to some fortran issue, one of the suggested fixes is using a docker image, the docker image works but how would I for example take a tensor in my main python script and perform a rounding operation on it using the docker version of the ttpy library?

Basically, do I use something like python on whales to call it from my main script and pass it a tensor?

Thanks.

Comment: An even simpler solution might be to just use the container for your script...doh. I should have suggested that first. You'll start the container in `shell` mode, install your editor of choice and write your code. Then execute the scripts within the container If you need to do this from outside the container, then create shell script that calls the container.

Comment: I think you are creating an XY Problem here. Maybe try asking a question about the installation issue, seems like that would actually solve your underlying problem

Answer (score 1):

A Docker container has an isolated filesystem.  If some library is only installed in a container, you can't `import` it from a non-container process.  Typically a Docker image will contain a complete application and not just a library.

In the particular GitHub repository you link to, the [Docker image](https://github.com/oseledets/ttpy#pre-built-docker-image) appears to principally provide a Python REPL for experimentation.  The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/oseledets/ttpy/blob/master/Dockerfile) is in the repository, and you can see what it does: it starts `FROM python:3.10`, installs some dependencies, and installs the `ttpy` library from the local sources, but it doesn't itself contain a `CMD`.

If this is a reasonable base for your application and you can use exactly the Python version this image packages then you could build an image `FROM daskol/ttpy`, but it might be more maintainable to repeat the installation steps from that Dockerfile in your own image.